# Order by based on product attributes availablity and stock mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables products and product attributes

```
products
id       product_name     
1             P1
2             P2
3             P3

product_attributes
id    product_id     size    stock
1          1          S        10
2          1          M        0
3          1          L        0
4          2          S        1
5          2          M        2
6          2          L        1
7          3          S        1
8          3          M        1

My expected output is like below:-
product_id    product_name
 2                 P2
 3                 P3
 1                 P1
```

So basically i want products at top having stock in all products attributes Like **P2** having stock in all attributes and stock sum is 4 and if you see the p3 also having the stock of all product attributes but sum of stock is less then P2 that is 2 only and P1 will goes down beacuse the M and L dont have stock.

```
select id as product_id, product_name from products Order BY ....
```

Can anyone help me to acheive the same?

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: i am trying to do subquery in Orderby but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its heart, I guess you're probably looking for something more like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,product_name CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1,'P1'),
(2,'P2'),
(3,'P3');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_attributes;

CREATE TABLE product_attributes
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,size CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,stock INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO product_attributes VALUES
(1,1,'S',10),
(2,1,'M', 0),
(3,1,'L', 0),
(4,2,'S', 1),
(5,2,'M', 2),
(6,2,'L', 1),
(7,3,'S', 1),
(8,3,'M', 1);


 SELECT product_id
   FROM product_attributes
  WHERE stock <> 0
  GROUP
     BY product_id
  ORDER
     BY COUNT(DISTINCT size) DESC;
+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|          2 |
|          3 |
|          1 |
+------------+
```